# Ruby Mixins Property

Tags: ruby, properties, mixins

Inspire by how datamapper used mixins, I need understand how to replicate the following using mixins

```
module Property
  def property(name, type, value)
    #Some code
  end
end

class Weapon 
  include Property

  property :name, :string, "The legendary Sword"
  property :attack, :integer, 10
end

class Item
  include Property

  property :name, :string, "Magic Carpet"
  property :description, :string, "Fly you to the moon"
end
```

But I've got an error,

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `property' for Route:Class
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, if you `include Property` in another class, all the instance methods become available to the instances of other class as instance methods.

In your case, you can use `extend Property` in the other class, so the instance methods of `Property` becomes class methods of the other class.

```
module Property
  def property(name, type, value)
    #Some code
  end
end

class Weapon 
  extend Property

  property :name, :string, "The legendary Sword"
  property :attack, :integer, 10
end
```

Or if you prefer using `include Property`, you can hook the module's `included` method, and add necessary methods there.

```
module Property
  def self.included(clazz)
    clazz.define_singleton_method(:property) do |name, type, value|
      p [name, type, value]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Arie, 

Thanks for you detailed explanation.

Comment: @GavinYap no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

So after following Arie's post, this is what I did

```
module Item
  def self.included(item)
    item.extend Property
  end         
end

module Property
def property(name, type, value)
  define_method(name) { p [name, type, value] }
end

class Weapon 
  include Item

  property :name, :string, "The legendary Sword"
  property :attack, :integer, 10
end
```